# Matters which are in doubt of being Haram or Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis

Throughout a persons life we may encounter situations where we have to make choices and we may not be sure of these choices of being Halal or Haram, we may try and apply logic to apply this through religion but some matters are too complicated and not explicitly mentioned in the Quran and even with the help of scholars, they may produce different opinions which really doesn't provide a solution!

Now would a person who has such a doubtful manner and unsure whether this manner will be halal or haram, what should a person do abandon that manner just in case or follow his instincts?

Or would it be best to seeks Allah's help through Dua and Salat Al Istikhara?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is doubtful, the Prophet told us it's better to abstain from it.

The Prophet is reported to have said:

> "The lawful is clear and the unlawful is clear, and between them are
>   doubtful matters about which many people do not know. **Thus he who
>   avoids doubtful matters clears himself in regard to his religion and
>   his honour,** but he who falls into doubtful matters [eventually]
>   falls into that which is unlawful, like the shepherd who pastures
>   around a sanctuary, all but grazing therein. Truly every king has a
>   sanctuary, and truly Allah’s sanctuary is His prohibitions. Truly in
>   the body there is a morsel of flesh, which, if it be whole, all the
>   body is whole, and which, if it is diseased, all of [the body] is
>   diseased. Truly, it is the heart.”

[(Sahih al-Bukhari)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/45) [(Sahih Muslim)](http://sunnah.com/muslim/22/133)

Comment: Jazak Allah Kher, would this also stand for verses within the Quran which scholars differ on when it comes to interpretation,lets say for example versus relating to jihad(this is just an example there are more)and music or the punishment of suicide?

Comment: Well differing is totally another issue.  Falling into Ikhtilaf is actually haraam and not allowed.  Prophet clearly said "Do not differ [ikhtilaf], for nations before you had differed and were destroyed." (Sahih al-Bukhari).  So differing is more proof of ignorance than it's of interpretation because we're suppose to take the verses on their apparent meaning without interpretation, unless the Prophet said they mean something else.  And many times the disputes can be settled if people really wanted to.  Jihad is fard, music isn't haram, punishment of suicide is hellfire.

Comment: If you want to discuss further you can speak in the chat or ask another question, otherwise the comments will get deleted by the moderators.

Answer (score 1):

Without making it too difficult. 
When it is unclear and there has been no mention in Qura'an or Hadith or any known scholar. Then go ask someone. 
If could not find anyone and you had to make a decision in a hurry, then think about what would please Allah most. What would serve humanity best and then do that.